Microservice in Kubernetes consumes a lot of memory, but in Jprofiler it shows less
I have the following image entering the pod, which the java process shows a 2.3GB memory
htop
But when you enter the Java application with JPolicter, it shows less memory
JProfiler
This is the dockerfile
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.9.1_1-alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
EXPOSE 13005 9010
ARG JAR_FILE=target/app-micro-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.jar

This is the helm
apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-micro 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-micro
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-micro 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app-micro
          image: acrclouster.azurecr.io/app-micro
          ports:
            - name: stack-app-port
              containerPort: 13005
            - name: stack-jmx-port
              containerPort: 9010
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 \
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010 \
                      -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"             
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: app-micro
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    ports:
    - port: 13005 
    selector:
        app: app-micro     

Try limiting the pod in Kubernetes by adding the following
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "2Gi"
            limits:
              memory: "3Gi"

but what this did was to be restarting the microservice constantly, I added more memory to the limit almost up to 6GB but it was still annoying
I also added another replica, so that there were 2 pods but these always increased and I was giving the node memory pressure
I would like to know why this difference in memory is shown and also, to know why that microservice is running a lot of memory, there are days that it even reaches 7GB

What is the value of JAVA_OPTS?

The value of JAVA_OPTS in in the helm of kubernetes

So you do not pass any -Xmx? You should pass something like -Xmx1g to keep the JVM under control
